# scanf formatting issue

Tags: php, formatting, scanf

I have a log file with the following format:

```
INFO 2011-03-09 10:26:15,270 [user] message
```

I want to parse the log file using PHP:

```
// assume file exists and all that
$handle = fopen("log_file.txt", "r");
while ($line_data = fscanf($handle, "%s %s %s [%s] %s\n")) {
    var_dump($line_data);
}
fclose($handle);
```

When I run this code I get:

```
[0]=>
 array(5) {
   [0]=> string(4) "INFO"
   [1]=> string(10) "2011-03-09"
   [2]=> string(12) "10:26:15,270"
   [3]=> string(5) "user]"
   [4]=> NULL
}
// snip
```

It appears the closing bracket in the format string ("%s %s %s [%s] %s") is disrupting the rest of the line from getting parsed.  I checked the PHP docs for scanf (as suggested by fscanf), and I didn't see anything mentioning having to escape a left bracket.

**Any suggestions on how to get the 4th and 5th elements to look like "user" and "message" respectively?**

Comment: i think its a bug in fscanf...

Answer (score 3):

Use the format

```
"%s %s %s [%[^]]] %s\n"
```

to prevent the 4th element taking any `]` character (of course this assumes there is no user having a `]` in the name).

(Example using sscanf: http://ideone.com/lJHYa)

---

The `%[abc]` format specifiers will make the function read a string consists of only characters `a`, `b` or `c`. The inverse, `%[^xyz]` will make the function read a string *not* having any of `x`, `y` and `z`.

Therefore, the `%[^]]` above will read a string until hitting a `]`.

Comment: aaah so this is how to escape it :P still regex is better :P

Comment: @n00b32 obligatory "now you have 2 problems"

Answer (score 0):

use regular expressions... if you really want fscanf, escape the bracket

---

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/scanf.html
:

> The bytes between the square brackets (the scanlist) comprise the scanset